# contrasting credible intervals with two different approaches

Tags: r, credible-interval, brms

I have a dataset that I'm modeling with bmrs in two ways: 1) trend across years and 2) comparison between decades.  I've obtained the credible intervals from both of the models two different ways, and there are considerable differences in the range of the CIs between the two approaches. How do I know which is correct?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidybayes)
library(brms)

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1970, 1999, 1), each = 20),
                 a = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 200, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(y  = (x/100)^2 + rnorm(600, 1, 2),
         yc = scale(y, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE),
         d  = as.factor(paste(str_sub(x, -2, -2), "0s", sep = "")))

m1 <- brm(yc ~ x, data = df) # model 1 has trends across years
m2 <- brm(yc ~ d, data = df) # model 2 compares values across decades

distinct(df, a, x) %>% 
  add_predicted_draws(m1) %>% 
  median_qi() %>%                              # calculate median and 95% CI's
  rename(Estimate = .prediction, loCI = .lower, hiCI = .upper) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = yc, group = x)) +                         # raw data
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = loCI, ymax = hiCI), col = "grey80", alpha = 0.2) + # 95% CI
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = Estimate)) +                  # median estimate
  facet_wrap(~a)

posterior_summary(m2) %>% data.frame() %>%                                      # obtain values
  rownames_to_column(var = "pred") %>% filter(grepl("b_", pred)) %>% 
  mutate(ycF = if_else(grepl("b_I", pred), Estimate, Estimate + min(Estimate)), # decadal adjustments
         loCI = if_else(grepl("b_I", pred), Q2.5, Q2.5 + min(Estimate)),
         hiCI = if_else(grepl("b_I", pred), Q97.5, Q97.5 + min(Estimate))) %>% 
  slice(rep(row_number(), 3)) %>% 
  mutate(d = rep(c("70s", "80s", "90s"), 3),
         a = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_boxplot(data = df, aes(x = d, y = yc, col = d)) +                  # raw data
  geom_linerange(aes(x = d, ymin = loCI, ymax = hiCI), linewidth = 0.6) + # 95% CI
  geom_point(aes(x = d, y = ycF), shape = 1, size = 2) +                  # median estimate
  facet_wrap(~a)
```

Plot # 1
[image]

Plot # 2
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. I'm not sure what you are comparing between the two plots but it seems to be apples and oranges. I believe your second model violates assumptions even more than the first model but both don't account for autocorrelation. `brm` does support inclusion of autocorrelation in your model formula.

Comment: @Roland My question is - why are the credible intervals so much wider in the first plot than the second?

Comment: Because they are not for the same estimates? And because you have issues with the assumption of independence, which should result in the credible intervals being too narrow?

Comment: right, they are not the same model, but they're from the same data, so it seems weird that the CIs are so different. I have not previously seen an autocorrelation term added to this type of model.

Comment: Look at the degrees of freedom. In the second model you have many more observations supporting each estimate, so of course the CIs are narrower. The issue is that these many more estimates are not actually independent and therefore the CIs are too narrow. That would also be the case to a lesser extent for the first model with real-world data. Include auto-correlation in your model.